# Unable to deduce why a segmentation fault occurs in my recursive function

Tags: c, recursion

I have experimented with my code a bit by commenting out specific parts of my code. I have found out that no segmentation fault occurs when i comment out the for loops with the variable j( shown in code). Also, when i comment out the recursive part in the function ( the lines where the function calls itself), no seg fault occurs even when the for loops are present. So clearly the for loops are causing problems in the second or higher iterations of the function, but I have no idea why. One possible reason i could think of is that infinite recursion occurs, but as far as i know no infinite recursion occurs here. 
I have been trying to solve the following problem: https://www.codechef.com/problems/H1

```
#include<stdio.h>
 int prime1[]={3,5,7,11,13,17};
 int min=1000000000;   //just some large number
 void check(int *, int);
 void swap(int*, int, int);
 int prime(int);
 int main()
 {
  int T;
  scanf("%d", &T);
  for(int i=0; i<T; i++)
  {
   printf("\n");
   int arr[9];
   for(int j=0; j<9; j++)
   scanf("%d", &arr[j]);
   check(arr, 0);
   if(min==1000000000)
    min=-1;
   printf("%d\n", min);
  } 
 }

 void check(int arr[],int  step)       //step indicates the level of     
                                       //iteration
 {
  int k,  a[9];
  for(k=0; k<9; k++)
  {
   if(arr[k]!=k+1)
    break;
  }
  if(k==9)
  {
   if(step<min)
    min=step;
  }
  else
  {
   for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
   {
    if(i%3!=2)
    {
     if(prime(arr[i]+arr[i+1]))
     {
      for(int j=0; j<9; j++)          // segmentation fault 
       a[j]=arr[j];
      swap(a, i, i+1);
      check(a, step+1);
     }
    }
    if(i<=5)
    {
     if(prime(arr[i]+arr[i+3]))
     {
      for(int j=0; j<9; j++)          // segmentation fault
       a[j]=arr[j];
      swap(a, i, i+3);
      check(a, step+1);
     }
    }
   }  
  }  
 }
 int prime(int a)
 {
  for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
  {
   if(a==prime1[i])
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
 }

 void swap( int a[], int b, int c)
 {
  int temp;
  temp=a[b];
  a[b]=a[c];
  a[c]=temp; 
 }
```

Comment: Recursion may cause seg. fault if too many recursions deep. But maybe this is not the case.

Comment: I do not see how the two lines after main() can compile. This does not seem to be a [mcve].

Comment: Could you edit to try for a more consistent and stronger indentation?

Comment: `arr[i+1]` can be indexing out of bounds, and `swap(a, i, i+1);` is more dangerous, since it is writing. In the second part of the function you limit the use of `i+3` with `if(i<=5)` but you have no such constraint in the first part, except for the dubious `if(i%3!=2)`.

Comment: Aside: don't forget that `2` is a prime number.

Comment: @WeatherVane There is a constraint in the first part. I have limited the variable i to 7 in the for loop. Also, I haven't included 2 in the array because, sum of no two distinct natural numbers is 2, hence not required for the problem

Comment: @Yunnosch I have made the required correction

Comment: Sorry then I can't see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm runs forever switching the first two tiles.
I removed some loops, `i=0`, `k=0` and `arr[] = {4,3,}` we are left with:

```
void check(int arr[], int step)
{
    int k, a[9];
    // arr[0] != 1, so k != 9, we fall in else { ... }
//  for (k = 0; k < 9; k++) {
//      if (arr[k] != k+1)
//          break;
//  }
//  printf("\n");
//  if (k == 9) {
//      if (step < min)
//          min = step;
//  } else {
        int i = 0;
//      for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
//          if (i%3 != 2) {
//              if (prime(arr[i] + arr[i+1])) {
                    // i = 0, so i%3 != 2, so we fall in the first if
                    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
                        a[j] = arr[j];
                    // you swap arr[0] with arr[1]
                    swap(a, i, i+1);
                    // and then you check again
                    check(a, step+1);
                    // and it runs so forever, never reaching this point
//              }
//          }
//          if (i <= 5) {
//              if (prime(arr[i] + arr[i+3])) {
//                  for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
//                      a[j] = arr[j];
//                  swap(a, i, i+3);
//                  check(a, step+1);
//              }
//          }
        }
    }
}
```

This algorithm needs rethinking. You need to differentiate the algorithm when run with different step number. The easiest is to switch a random title on each check, the better is to build a proper decision tree, where you remember which titles were switched.
You may interest yourself in some [proper indentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html),